# How do I generate contour plot from a n x n matrix?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a n x n matrix called `o_potential` filled with some values and would like to generate a contour plot out of it. I tried several approaches without any success. This is what I have right now.

```
n = 20
x = arange(0,n-1)
y = arange(0,n-1)
plt.contourf(x, y, o_potential[x][y])
plt.show()
```

`o_potential` looks like this

```
o_potential = [[ -1.,          -1.,          -1.,          -1.,          -1.        ],
 [ 10.,           4.12244898,   2.7755102,    4.12244898,  10.        ],
 [ 10.,           5.7755102,    4.24489796,   5.7755102,   10.        ],
 [ 10.,           4.12244898,   2.7755102,    4.12244898,  10.        ],
 [ -1.,          -1.,          -1.,          -1.,          -1.        ]]
```

I am getting the following error message: "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type."

I have been struggling with this from yesterday. I tried almost all the Google results, but couldn't solve the problem. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: What is o_potential and why are you indexing it with the x and y arrays?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
n = 20
x = arange(n)
y = arange(n)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contourf(X, Y, o_potential)
plt.show()
```

or just

```
plt.contourf(o_potential)
plt.show()
```

It's hard to say exactly what the problem is since you don't show o_potential, but the above will likely work.

Comment: @eryksun: thanks for the note, and I edited this a bit.  I guess I was trying to stay within the conceptual framework of the OP and make minimal changes.  Of course, feel free to write your preferred soln.

Comment: Ok, so basically I have n x n matrix with numerical values on it. I need to generate a contour plot. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Actually I found that imshow() does the work--though I am not how imshow() is different than contour plot. Another quick question, how do I remove the labels for the gridlines?

Comment: @entanglement: imshow and contourf show a similar thing slightly differently.  The imshow basically shows the value at each of the specified points (often called a "heatmap"), as can be most clearly seen by setting `interpolation="nearest"`; and imshow can also be used to show images, etc.  Contour plots are basically a set of iso-lines, like on a topographical map (i.e., it really all about the lines of constant z-value).

Comment: @entanglement: removing labels from gridlines is a quite different topic, so it's probably best to post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(o_potential, cmap='viridis')
```